# Get Apps for Admins connection fails to show next page of apps

Tags: power-automate, power-platform

I'm encountering these issues using the Get Apps for Admins connector.   I am trying to get a list of all apps in an environment.  The first issue is that in spite of having about 100 apps in the environment, the connector only returns 47.   I've seen this in other environments as well, although the count varies from environment to environment.

So the flow is changed to use the next link from one action as the skip token for another action.  This is the formula I'm using to aet a string variable to avoid several compose actions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After discussion with Microsoft, we discovered that supplying a value for Page size causes the output NextLink to have a different format than than if the value is omitted.  If you leave Page size blank, the connector works.